# How do I specify the storage IDE primary master VDI file in VirtualBox from a Vagrantfile?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I tried giving the path to the `.vdi` file on this line

```
config.vm.box = "../build/qMp_3.2.1-Clearance_VirtualBox_x86_factory_20170406-2203.vdi"
```

but it complain it could not open the file. I think Vagrant is looking for a box file. I tried

```
config.vm.box = "base"
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--medium", "../build/qMp_3.2.1-Clearance_VirtualBox_x86_factory_20170406-2203.vdi"]
```

but it gave an error

> Couldn't open file /C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/mesh/node/base

I tried

```
vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', "../build/qMp_3.2.1-Clearance_VirtualBox_x86_factory_20170406-2203.vdi"]
```

but it gave the same error.

So how do I specify the VDI file in a `Vagrantfile`?